# Can I Upload my own videos on my website and also on youtube channel?

Tags: content, copyright, youtube

I'm a teacher and have created some tutorial videos (from computer screen and webcam with my face). I'm in IRAN and we get into trouble using YouTube. (YouTube access is restricted from our country)

I want to share my all videos on my own site (self-hosted video and share them on my website). I also want to share some of these videos on my YouTube channel.

1. Is this action against YouTube policy? I share my own video on my site (as self-hosted) and also upload them on my YouTube channel. Note that the sharing on my website is not embeded from YouTube or something, I will upload them on my own server directly.
2. If this is not against the rules, can it cause problems for my channel in the future? (like not being monetized or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely upload and share your videos from your website, it has nothing to do with YouTube.

And if you can access YouTube in the future, you can also upload the same videos there, as long as the videos don't violate YouTube policies.